# Parameters with DataProviders

Tags: selenium, java, testng

Is there any way to use Parameters with `DataProvider` together in *Selenium* ?

```
  @Parameters({"safaf"})

  @DataProvider(name="sss")

  public void hhhhh (String safaf){

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done.
Parameter passing in TestNG can be done two ways:

1. Using `@Parameter` tag and you pass the value from your `testng.xml`
   Useful when your dealing with simple parameter
2. Using `@DataProvider` tag
   Useful if your reading values from prop file or database.

So your testng.xml will look something of this sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite123">
   <test name="test123">
   <parameter name="safaf" value="blah"/> 
   <classes>
     <class name="DataProvider123" />
  </classes>
   </test>
  </suite>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work!

        @Parameters({"path"})

        @Test(priority=2,dataProvider="db")

 public void description2( String path,String item)

I got this error (The data provider is trying to pass 1 parameters but the method com.macys.NewTest#description2 takes 2 and TestNG is unable in inject a suitable object)!!!!

anyway, Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, i wasn't precise earlier.

Do not use both the annotation together on @Test.

Follow the below approach:
`
 String myParam;

 @BeforeClass
  @Parameters("test")
  public void one(String p1) {
   p1 = this.myParam;
  }

 @Test(dataProvider="dp")
 public void two(String p2){
 }

Comment: Did that solve your problem ?

Comment: No, i was looking for something else. I've changed my code to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

DataProvider is a method in a class that returns a two dimensional an array of object (Object [ ][ ]) to the test method. The test method will be called m times in the m*n type of object array.
Where m ➨ The first array m represents the number of rows that has to be repeated your test m number of times.
           n ➨ The second array n represents a column that is the number of parameters in the test data. 
This method is annotated with @DataProvider. [DataProvider in TestNG](https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/05/testng-dataprovider.html)